# How do I remove properly html5 audio without appending to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

With Javascript, I have a function that creates an audio element with `createElement("audio")`, and start playing in loop without using `appendChild()`, I mean without appending it to the DOM.
The element created is kept in a variable, let's called it `music1`:

```
music = document.createElement("audio");
 music.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
 music.play();
});
music.setAttribute("src", music_Source);
```

What I would like to do, is to change the music played, if possible using the same function, and storing the element in the same variable.

What I do is that before the code above:

```
if(typeof(music) == "object") {
 music.pause();
 music = null;
}
```

But: if I remove `music.pause()`, the first music keeps playing, and the second starts playing too at the same time, which makes me think that the first music is always somewhere in the document/in the memory. Also, `music = null` seems useless. I don't want to use jQuery.

Do you have any idea to properly remove the first music, delete the element, or so on?

Actually, kennis' comment is right, I tried to just change the src attribute, and not modify the "music" variable (neither setting it to null, nor re-creating an Element) and it seem to work too. So, for the record: For each source changing here is the function:

```
if(typeof(music) != "object") {
  //audio element does not exist yet:
  music = document.createElement("audio");
  music.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
    music.play();
  });
}
music.setAttribute("src", music_Source);
```

Comment: You've already answered your question! `music.pause()` before deleting the object.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to just change the 'src' attribute when you're ready to start the new song?

Comment: @kennis Actually, `music.setAttribute("src", music_Source);` is called again with the new music_Source for the 2nd music, so I guess that's what you mean, I change the src attribute. @Francis Avila But I'm not really convinced that music.pause() before deleting allows the previous music to be "deleted" in any proper way. Or maybe I miss something, or I don't explain myself well enough :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

rather than delete, the better way of doing it would be to change the src

```
music.setAttribute('src',theNewSource); //change the source
music.load(); //load the new source
music.play(); //play
```

that way you're always dealing with the same object so you hit the DOM less often, and also you avoid your problem of having two player at the same time

Also make sure you use the .load method to load the new audio, otherwise it will keep playing the old one.

Comment: Actually it seems to work without load(), the previous music stops and the new starts playing. It seems that the music starts loading when the source is changed (on Chrome at least, as I work on a webkit-specific app). But changing the source is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The original object would be deleted, but only when the garbage collector determines that it's time. The fact that it's `audio` may complicate things and make it difficult for the browser to make that determination.

So, yes, just re-use the original object instead.

Answer (score 1):

While reusing the HTMLAudioElements is definitely the best option -for completeness- you should be able to dispose it by just clearing the `src` or `srcObj`:

```
music.srcObj = null;
```

This more or less lets the GC of your browser know that the element is ready for removal.

Comment: the only issue with this solution is that, not being standard, it triggers a warning in the console `Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed.` (at least in Firefox 122). I don't know if in the future it can throw an exception or do something unexpected. In regard to garbage collection, MDN says that once there are no references and the playback stops, [only then it becomes subject to GC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio#memory_usage_and_management). So if there's still some reference to the Audio object, it will remain in memory