# Creating and removing `<audio>` tags via javascript (possible scope issue)

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am a neophyte JS developer with a past in server-side programming.

I am creating a simple web app that allows various users to engage in live audio chatting with one another. Whenever a new user logs into an audio chat room, the following ensures they can hear everyone talking

```
// plays remote streams
async function playStreams(streamList) {

    await Promise.all(streamList.map(async (item, index) => {

        // add an audio streaming unit, and play it
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
            audio.play();
        });
        audio.srcObject = item.remoteStream;
        audio.id = 'audio-stream-'+item.streamID;
        audio.muted = false;
        
    }));
}
```

Essentially I pass a list of streams into that function and play all of them.

Now if a user leaves the environment, I feel the prudent thing to do is to destroy their `<audio>` element.

To achieve that, I tried

```
function stopStreams(streamList) {

    streamList.forEach(function (item, index) {
        let stream_id = item.streamID;
        let audio_elem = document.getElementById('audio-stream-'+stream_id);
        if (audio_elem) {
            audio_elem.stop();
        }
    });

}
```

Unfortunately, `audio_elem` is always `null` in the function above. It is not that the streamIDs are mismatched - I have checked them.

Maybe this issue has to do with scoping? I am guessing the `<audio>` elements created within `playStreams` are scoped within that function, and thus `stopStreams` is unable to access them.

I need a domain expert to clarify whether this is actually the case. Moreover, I also need a solution regarding how to better handle this situation - one that cleans up successfully after itself.

---

p.s. a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864617/how-do-i-remove-properly-html5-audio-without-appending-to-dom) came close to asking the same thing. But their case was not numerous `<audio>` elements being dynamically created and destroyed as users come and go. I do not know how to use that answer to solve my issue. My concepts are unclear.

Comment: You _created_ audio elements, but you did not actually append them to the document anywhere - so `document.getElementById` _can’t_ find them, because that is only for elements that are part of the current document’s DOM. Your audio elements currently exist only in JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe: Actually I have no need to display any `<audio>` widgets to users, which is why I did not append them. But are you suggesting that if I want to gracefully create and destroy these elements, I will need to append them to the DOM no matter what?

Comment: No, you don’t _need_ to add them to the document, but if you don’t, _then_ you will have to find a way to make them accessible from outside of the function where you are creating them. `var audio` creates a local variable, that is indeed limited to the scope of that function. You need to store the references to them into an array or something, that is accessible from both your functions.

Comment: @CBroe: I wrote an answer to my own question based on the hints you provided. Can you have a look and do a sanity check on that. It would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I created a global dictionary like so -

`const liveStreams = {};`

Next, when I play live streams, I save all the `<audio>` elements in the aforementioned global dictionary -

```
// plays remote streams
async function playStreams(streamList) {

    await Promise.all(streamList.map(async (item, index) => {

        // add an audio streaming unit, and play it
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
            audio.play();
        });
        audio.srcObject = item.remoteStream;
        audio.muted = false;

        // log the audio object in a global dictionary
        liveStreams[stream_id] = audio;
        
    }));
}
```

I destroy the streams via accessing them from the `liveStreams` dictionary, like so -

```
function stopStreams(streamList) {
    
        streamList.forEach(function (item, index) {
            let stream_id = item.streamID;

            // Check if liveStreams contains the audio element associated to stream_id
            if (liveStreams.hasOwnProperty(stream_id)) {
                let audio_elem = liveStreams[stream_id];
                // Stop the playback
                audio_elem.pause();// now the object becomes subject to garbage collection.
                // Remove audio obj's ref from dictionary
                delete liveStreams.stream_id;
            }
        });
    
    }
```

And that does it.